# Angular PWA: Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I created a Angular / PWA web for testing

> *ng new provaPWA*

and install PWA module

> npm install -g @angular/cli

I uploaded the code to the server,  at this URL

> https://elmultiusos.net/

the manifest.json appears, but when i click in "Add to home screen", appears this error:

> > Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

According to Angular / PWA instructions when generating the distribution

> ng build

Two files should be created

> . ngsw-worker.js
>   . ngsw.json

But they are not generated

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli` installs the Angular CLI globally. It doesn't install any PWA module, like you seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

`ng new projectName`  is not enough to enable pwa yet. there are still several steps more to take. follow the tutorial here in angular official document https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started